# How to get uint8_t data of uint32_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working with a microcontroller where the sensor I'm trying to interface sends uint8_t data. The issue is I can read the pin with a uint32_t function.

So I guess I can read the pin with the uint32_t, but I have to "extract" it. But I'm getting nonsense...

```
uint32_t number = 429496729;

uint8_t x1 = (number >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
uint8_t x2 = (number >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
uint8_t x3 = (number >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
uint8_t x4 = (number >> (8*3)) & 0xff;
```

printing x3 for instance gives me "™". Same with x1. Whats going on here?

Comment: What "read the pin" mean? Please show how you print it, but a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem would be even better.

Comment: What values did you expect?

Comment: It's just how `cout` (and other output streams) print `char`s. If you want to see the numbers, do something like `std::cout << int(x1);`.

Comment: 'interface sends uint8_t data. The issue is I can read the pin with a uint32_t function' -.. what?  What happens if the interface receives just one byte?  2 bytes?  Three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, "™" is exactly what you should expect.

```
// 0x19999999 - NOTE: you'd need an extra '5' on the end to make it MAX_UNIT. eg. 0xFFFFFFFF
uint32_t number = 429496729; 

uint8_t x1 = (number >> (8*0)) & 0xff; // 0x99
uint8_t x2 = (number >> (8*1)) & 0xff; // 0x99
uint8_t x3 = (number >> (8*2)) & 0xff; // 0x99
uint8_t x4 = (number >> (8*3)) & 0xff; // 0x19
```

If you go look up the ["™"](https://www.alt-codes.net/trademark_alt_code.php) symbol in extended ascii, it maps to 153, eg. 0x99h.